Efficient and unbiased estimation of the location ($\mu$) of truncated normal distribution with known scale ($\sigma^2$) and truncation points
I have one observation $x$ which I know comes from the following truncated normal distribution:
$$x \sim TN(\mu, \sigma^2, -\delta, \delta) \;\textrm{ where }\; \delta > 0$$
In my problem, the scale parameter $\sigma^2$ and the truncation points $-\delta$ and $\delta$ are known, but $\mu$ is not.
I know that we can obtain $\hat{\mu}$ through maximum likelihood estimation:
$$\hat{\mu} = argmax_{\mu \in \mathbb{R}} \frac{\phi\left(\frac{x - \mu}{\sigma}\right)}{\sigma\left(\Phi\left(\frac{\delta - \mu}{\sigma}\right) - \Phi\left(\frac{-\delta - \mu}{\sigma}\right)\right)}$$
But because I only have one observation, I am finding in simulations that the consistency guarantees of MLE are not sufficient and I actually have considerable bias in my estimates (here they find a similar bias issue with MLE in the comments). So my questions are:

For my estimation problem, are there any alternative estimators that deliver lower variance than MLE?
Does a bias correction for the MLE estimator $\hat{\mu}$ in my case exist and/or how can I find it?

Because my case (known $\sigma$ and truncation $-\delta, \delta$) is not typically analysed in the literature, I have been unsuccessful in finding anything specific to my problem in textbooks or research articles. Everything I have consulted (e.g. Clifford (1991)) discusses the more general case of many samples and unknown $\mu$ and $\sigma$ with unrestricted $a$ and $b$ truncation points.
Any help is much appreciated. Answers that rely on numerical methods are perfectly acceptable.
Reference: Cohen, A. Clifford. Truncated and censored samples: theory and applications. CRC press, 1991.

One observation is not enough to infer $\mu$ with much accuracy at all.  I think you are inherently going to be limited by your lack of data.
I suspect the best you can do is take a Bayesian approach.  Specifically:

Treat $\mu$ as a random variable, and postulate a prior for it, based on your domain knowledge.  Let $p_\mu(\cdot)$ denote the pdf for this distribution (the prior).

Use Bayes law to estimate the pdf for the conditional distribution of $\mu$ given $x$.

Do whatever you want with this posterior distribution on $x$.  For instance, if you want a point estimate, compute the expected value of the posterior.  In many applications, rather than picking a point estimate, it might be better to model the implications of different values of $x$, weight them by the posterior pdf, and use that to choose an action.


To expand on this a little bit: Let $p(\mu | x)$ denote the conditional pdf of $\mu$ given $x$, and $p(x | \mu)$ the conditional pdf of $x$ given $\mu$.  Note that $p(x | \mu)$ is the pdf of the truncated normal distribution, i.e.,
$$p(x|\mu) = {1 \over C \sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac12 (\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})^2},$$
where $C$ is a normalizing constant to ensure this pdf integrates to 1.  Specifically, $C = \Pr[-\delta \le t \le \delta]$ if $t \sim \mathbb{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$.  Therefore,
$$C = \Phi(\frac{\delta-\mu}{\sigma}) - \Phi(\frac{-\delta-\mu}{\sigma}).$$
Now we can apply Bayes law to discover
$$p(\mu|x) = {p(x|\mu) p(\mu) \over p(x)}
= \frac{1}{C'} p(x|\mu) p(\mu),$$
where $C'=p(x)$ is a normalizing constant, specifically,
$$C' = \int_{\mu=-\delta}^{\delta} p(x|\mu) p(\mu) \; d\mu.$$
In this way, you obtain a formula for $p(\mu|x)$.  Evaluating it likely requires numerical integration.
If you want a point estimate, compute the expected value of $\mu$ conditioned on $x$, specifically
$$\int_{\mu=-\delta}^{\delta} \mu p(\mu|x) \; d\mu.$$
If you want to compute this, then a simplistic approach is to evaluate $p(\mu|x)$ at many values of $\mu$ (using numerical integration), then approximate the expected value with a weighted sum $\sum_i \mu_i p(\mu_i|x)$.
There may well be better (more efficient) ways to estimate the posterior distribution $p(\mu|x)$ or its expected value.  The community at Statistics Stack Exchange are in the best position to help you identify methods that are appropriate for that.
Ultimately, this is going to be limited by the fact that you only have one observation, so there will remain a lot of uncertainty about $\mu$.

Thank you for your post. Much of my paper is directed towards a frequentist audience who I know will view the introduction of a Bayesian framework as "an estimator which is biased towards the prior" -  so it is not an ideal solution. But I will dwell on this and see if my overall work can be motivated from a Bayesian perspective instead... Many thanks!

@Tele, that concern makes sense.  I hope someone else will be able to suggest other possibilities so you have multiple options.
